# Json_array in doctrine symfony

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I i am trying to insert json data in my db with doctrine for some reason i can not insert data in the db

here is my code

```
namespace ScheduleBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

//Json Response
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

//Class Controller
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

//Request
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use ScheduleBundle\Entity\schedule;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("/api/{week}")
   */
  public function roosterApi(Request $request, $week)
  {
    //
    //
    // print_r($rooster);
    //
    // echo 'Rooster: ' . $dataRooster->getSchedule();
    $rooster = array('week' => '1');

    $roosterConnection = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('ScheduleBundle:schedule', 'schedule');
    $dataRooster = $roosterConnection->findOneByStudentId('36838');


    $dataRooster->setSchedule($rooster);

    $out = array('1' => $week);

    return new JsonResponse($out, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
  }
}
```

This is my entity

```
namespace ScheduleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * schedule
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="schedule")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ScheduleBundle\Repository\scheduleRepository")
 */
class schedule
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="student_id", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $studentId;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="schedule", type="json_array")
     */
    private $schedule;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set studentId
     *
     * @param string $studentId
     *
     * @return schedule
     */
    public function setStudentId($studentId)
    {
        $this->studentId = $studentId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get studentId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStudentId()
    {
        return $this->studentId;
    }

    /**
     * Set schedule
     *
     * @param array $schedule
     *
     * @return schedule
     */
    public function setSchedule($schedule)
    {
        $this->schedule = $schedule;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get schedule
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSchedule()
    {
        return $this->schedule;
    }
}
```

I am using doctrine and symfony 3.0

edit: added all the code i have in my file. i am also getting no errors.
      Added the entity code

Comment: Please add the code where you insert the data. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Also the mapping metadata of your ScheduleBundle:schedule entity could be helpful.

Comment: @JimL i am getting no erros and this is how i insert data

Comment: You forgotten to save. See the answer given, it give you the solution, but you should look a minimum at the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database) before ask here :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell doctrine to persist (and flush) your changes

```
$entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$roosterConnection = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('ScheduleBundle:schedule', 'schedule');
$dataRooster = $roosterConnection->findOneByStudentId('36838');

$dataRooster->setSchedule($rooster);

$entityManager->persist($dataRooster);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i think it worked for my problem but it gave me the next error The class 'ScheduleBundle\Entity\schedule' was not found in the chain configured namespaces StudentsBundle\Entity

Comment: Check your spelling, also class names should conventionally be Uppercase, I'm not sure if this is the cause of your issue because I always make all class names start with a uppercase letter. The error is telling you the problem, so ask yourself, "Why is 'ScheduleBundle\Entity\schedule' not found in `configured namespaces StudentsBundle\Entity`?"